# Firebase concurrency read/write

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase mobile application that serves many users.

The application requires to send email notifications to users. Firebase cannot send functional email.

Zapier is not an option as the webhook service is very limited and cant consume complex JSON such as the email body.

To solve this, I store the “email job” in the Firebase database (include To, subject and body”), I setup a “mail server” using nodejs server (at home) that listen to the Firebase database, so whenever there is a “new email job” it sends the mail and mark the job status to “DONE”.

In order to maintain high availability and scalability, I must be able to run more than one “mail servers” but this will cause duplication mail as all servers will listen to jobs.

I cannot address a job to a specific server, as the server may be down and I will lose jobs. Also, Firebase does not have kind of `SELECT FOR UPDATE` as SQL databases have to maintain concurrency.

Is there a way to solve this issue using Firebase? If no, any workaround?

Comment: This might be useful: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-queue